# How to omit checking of PHP dependency for composer?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I've made an update of software in one of a production server and got error:

```
Installation request for symfony/http-foundation v2.5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v2.5.0].
- symfony/http-foundation v2.5.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
```

That's right, because on that server I've got PHP 5.3.1. Unfortunately I don't have rights to update it. Can I somehow omit this check of PHP version? I don't know how but on another server (where also is PHP 5.3.1) the error doesn't come out.

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP version wouldn't be important, the Symfony package would define the PHP requirement to be "5.3.0" instead of "5.3.3".

There is a [severe backwards incompatible change in 5.3.3](http://php.net/releases/5_3_3.php) compared to previous 5.3 versions.

Are you prepared to deal with this? Do you want to apply a workaround for this issue? The you could clone the original project, fix the issues relating to that change, adjust the `composer.json` of that project, and add your cloned repo to the application you want to install. Done.

You could also extract all the files from that Symfony package, commit it into that application, add an autoloader definition for these classes to the application `composer.json`, and also add `"replace":{"symfony/http-foundation":"2.5.0"}` to satisfy any other dependency.

Best thing to do: Explain to the server administrator that the PHP version is too old to run the software, and that this PHP release from November 2009 should be retired and be updated with all the serious security patches that accumulated over the 5 years of maintenance (the last PHP version is 5.3.29, released 2014-08-14). Do note that upgrading to 5.4 or 5.5 will also give you performance improvements for free.

Comment: I've made a server administrator to upgrade PHP to 5.4, ufff. But I made a little research and have found out that on servers where was 5.3.10 everything was OK, but on those where was 5.3.2 I got that error. Any idea why?

Comment: 5.3.2 is still less that the required PHP version 5.3.3 - that's why.

Comment: Doesn't matter I've just realized that the 5.3.1 != 5.3.10, damn... so simple.